# ADC and RC filter importance

Tags: analog, adc, filter, passive-filter, aliasing

[TI](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sbaa277a/sbaa277a.pdf?ts=1647702002317) and [ADI](https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/front-end-amp-and-rc-filter-design.html#refs) suggest using an RC filter, ADI noted that SAR ADC have switching kickback and say it's really important but [STmicroelectronic](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/cd00211314-how-to-get-the-best-adc-accuracy-in-stm32-microcontrollers-stmicroelectronics.pdf) says the components of the RC filter discussed in the TI and ADI papers are parasitic, STmicroelectronic als says it is best to avoid both 'Ain' and 'Cp'. If you have parasitic C then your series resitor must be limited.

If I have an active high order anti-aliasing filter before a SAR DAC filter, do I still need an RC filter to reduce ADC kick-back?

Maybe the TI and ADI papers considering precision and lower sampling rates but ST has covered the general and for example also aquiring of audio signal.

Or is related to OpAmp's selling time. And it's formulation is on the ADI's paper, mentioned.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, thanks to all lovely people who answered and inspired me. [Here](https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/raqs/raq-issue-84.html) is a tutorial on why ADC driver is needed. Rc filter, as discussed in AD paper, mentioned in question, is used to 1.Adapting to settling time needed by ADC and 2. Anti alisasing filter or bandwdth limiter. I think settling time is what is countering the ADC current spikes. Then you must calculate the required settling time of your sampling rate, then compare if your filter (last stage of filter) settling time is less than that or not. The calculations will be uploaded later.

In case you use Sallen key active filter probably you have high frequency leakage, using RC filter in last stage is good practice to remove them.

Answer (score 5):

If you look in the data sheet for the analog to digital converter (ADC), you'll find a section on the input structure of the ADC which is a switched capacitor topology. In the following figure copied from the Analog Devices AD4680 (chosen at random), the text explains that C1 is parasitic capacitance (pin and wire bond), about 3 pF. R1 is the switch on resistance, about 200 ohms. C2 is the sampling capacitor, about 15 pF.

The switching of C2 will cause a current spike when the switch is closed which will upset the amplifier feeding the ADC causing a voltage change at the output of the driver and possibly ringing. By placing an RC circuit at the input of the ADC, the RC circuit's capacitance will provide the current when the switch is closed without disturbing the output of the driving circuit.

Bottom line, read the specification sheet for the particular ADC you are using and heed the input circuitry suggestions.

[image: AD4680 input structure]

Comment: Reading the data sheet for the ADC is really all it boils down to. Some ADCs have built in input buffers that don’t require any glitch filter while others need a higher order filter than just an RC can provide.

Answer (score 2):

You can drive most capacitive switching SAR ADC’s directly with a small isolation resistor and a fast op-amp that will settle with enough accuracy on-time. Either you need an op-amp that includes the settling times in its datasheet specifications, or you'll have to qualify any other op-amp for the application yourself. No way around that.

You can aid this driver’s job by adding a charge storage capacitor between the ADC input pin and the common. The series resistor feeding that capacitor will act to stabilize the op-amp. The capacitor will convert the charge injected by the ADC into a voltage step. When this voltage step is low enough relative to the capacitance used, the op-amp will have time to re-settle the capacitor to within the 0.5LSB.

There usually is often optimal capacitance for any given resistance, where if you make it bigger, the op-amp is unable to recharge the larger capacitor on time, or if you make it smaller, the step is too large in spite of the op-amp doing its best. The idea then is to vary the series resistance, and for each resistance find the capacitance that yields the smallest step, and select the resistance for which the optimum capacitance had overall lowest step.

Op-amp based filters don’t perform well when directly feeding ADC inputs. The ADC “kick” injects charge into the filter’s capacitors, and that charge decays according to the time constant of the filter -- usually way too slow to avoid the sampling error in the ADC.

Answer (score 0):

> *The raised question for me is if I have active high order Anti-Aliasing
> filter before SAR DAC filter, still I need RC filter (to reduce ADC
> kick-back)?*

If there is a (decent) capacitor at the input of your ADC that is part of your anti-alias filter then, it's likely that this will also supply sufficient energy needed by the ADC when it samples your input signal to avoid a voltage glitch error of more than 0.5 least significant bits.

Comment: I mean, you told: rc can help reduce voltage glitch. This is qualitative. But I need more quantitative explanation to be able to determine I need that rc or not, I hope this clarify.

Comment: That's a different question to what you originally asked in your question. You asked: *do I still need an RC filter to reduce ADC kick-back?* and the answer is "probably". If you want a mathematical analysis of the glitch-reducing capability that your anti-alias filter capacitor provides, I'm sure you know what to do. It's all based on Q=CV and how much charge your ADC input steals when it samples vs how much of a voltage glitch you can tolerate.

Comment: I think that kick-back is being managed by OpAmps setlling time. and maybe that RC settling time help OpAmp to change it's settling time!? As mentineon on ADI paper referred in qestion.